# Ngfor not displaying

Tags: angular, ionic3

Provider work, but *ngFor not displaying.

In the image below, you can see that the provider loads the data but is not shown on the screen.

What could be wrong? The API is returning the data correctly, only the view is not happening.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5xwf.png)

Code.html

```
  <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
  <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
    <ion-title>Deputado</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary" stacked>Qual deputado?</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" (input)="buscarDeputado($event, searchKey)"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-list>  
        <ion-item *ngFor="let deputado of deputados" (click)="selecionarDeputado($event, deputado)">
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                  <img src="https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/{{deputado.id}}.jpg"/>
            </ion-avatar>
            <h2>{{deputado.nome}}</h2>
            <p class="item-description">{{deputado.siglaPartido}}</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list> 
</ion-content>
```

Code.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CamaraProvider } from '../../providers/camara/camara';
import { DetalhedeputadoPage } from '../detalhedeputado/detalhedeputado';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-deputado',
  templateUrl: 'deputado.html',
  providers: [
    CamaraProvider
  ]
})
export class DeputadoPage {

  deputados: Array<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private camaraProvider: CamaraProvider) {
  }

  buscarDeputado(event, key) {
        if(event.target.value.length > 2) {
            this.camaraProvider.getDeputado(event.target.value).subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.deputados = data.results; 
                    console.log(data);  
                }   
            );
        }
    }  



    selecionarDeputado(event, deputado) {
        this.navCtrl.push(DetalhedeputadoPage, {
            deputado: deputado
        });
    }    

}
```

Provider.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class CamaraProvider {

  private baseApiPath = "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/";

  constructor(public http: Http){

  }


  getDeputado(deputadoName) {
    var url = this.baseApiPath + 'deputados?nome=' + encodeURI(deputadoName);
    var response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
    return response;
  }  


}
```

Provider works perfectly, but does not show the results on the page.

Comment: Try to change `deputados: Array<any>;` to `deputados: any[];`

Comment: It did not work, thank you.

Comment: In `buscarDeputado` function, try to change `this.deputados = data.results;` to `this.deputados = data.dados;`

Comment: is this.deputados = data.dados;  (not data.result). Anyway, I'll use httpClient, not the old and deprecated http, see https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Perfect.....work now...thank you @Renata!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not getting the right value in the `buscarDeputado` function. There is no `results` value at the image you have attached. In `buscarDeputado` function, try to change `this.deputados = data.results;` to `this.deputados = data.dados;`.

```
buscarDeputado(event, key) {
    if(event.target.value.length > 2) {
        this.camaraProvider.getDeputado(event.target.value).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.deputados = data.dados; 
                console.log(data);  
            }   
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The results returned is an array of objects not just objects, so you have to access to them with a key, try the following:

```
<ion-list>  
    <ion-item *ngFor="let deputado of deputados; let i = index" (click)="selecionarDeputado($event, deputado)">
        <ion-avatar item-left>
            <img src="https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/{{deputado[i].id}}.jpg"/>
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{deputado[i].nome}}</h2>
        <p class="item-description">{{deputado[i].siglaPartido}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

in your ts:

```
buscarDeputado(event, key) {
    if(event.target.value.length > 2) {
        this.camaraProvider.getDeputado(event.target.value).subscribe(
            data => this.deputados = data.dados; 
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dados` seems to be a property of `results` and is the one which is an array instead of `results` itself.

```
this.camaraProvider.getDeputado(event.target.value).subscribe(
     data => {
        this.deputados = data.results.dados; // include appropriate null checks
     }
);
```